# SQLITE3 python - SELECT sql query with placeholders giving error

Tags: python, sqlite

feel free to comment and tell me if the title needs changing, anyway, I've been trying to query my "User_Messages" Table and get any messages related to an id. This is the line of code im using:

`c.execute("SELECT * FROM User_Messages  WHERE ID = $1", (ID))` (id is an integer eg. 190332830289)

it keeps giving out this error when I run it from terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

however when ran from a .py file it returns None and fails to give out an error.
Any ideas how I should solve this?

On an related note can I also use a placeholder for the table name? something like this:
`SELECT * FROM %1 WHERE ID = %2` so that I can pass in multiple table names?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a tuple --> `(ID,)`

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

and an example:

```
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
```

Comment: Any idea how to replace the table name as well?

Comment: @IsaacWP121 - the placeholder concept of the SQL API is not relevant  to the table name. You will have to do it your self. Did `(ID,)` work for you?